# Auto-suppression Lists in Mobile Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, mobilepush

Is there a way to stop Journey Builder from sending an SMS via SMS activity or Push notification via Push activity to a defined list of Subscribers ?

This list is updated in real-time by API calls from Service Cloud.

In Email, I can use Auto-Supression Lists to achieve this. But I have no clue on how to use this for Mobile Studio.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this. I also need to auto suppress contacts receiving SMS and Push.

Comment: @neo2049 not really. this feature is still missing.